# Is there a rule which states that all questions and answers have to be in English on this site?

Tags: discussion, answers, scope, languages

I know that people often tell others that it is a rule here, but I am have never actually seen it written anywhere, so is it a rule that all questions and answers on this site have to be written in English?

If people who don't speak English though are not allowed to close questions as unclear to them, we shouldn't be allowed to close questions in other languages just because they are unclear for us. If we want to close something, there should be a rule against it, so I think that something about this should be put in the help section, otherwise there is no real justification for closing the questions. And how are users to know that it's an English only site if it is not officially written anywhere?

Comment: Related, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275643

Comment: Yes, according too this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Comment: "And how are users to know that it's an English only site if it is not officially written anywhere?" Presumably users have brains and can deduce this by observing that the rest of the site is in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since majority of the users on the stack network speaks english or is from english speaking countries,  English is a de facto language of the site. This is supported by links Mateo and Mark posted in the comments.

However, I understand not all users on the site are capable of understanding technical vocabulary. Personally , I sometimes write answers in both English and users' language.  This is acceptable practice. Your answers don't just help one specific question but others who may stumble upon. Hence it's good to make them as accessible as possible

Community members who speak another language also should aid question askers in translation so that they are accessible to  community

Comment: If people who don't speak English though are not allowed to close questions as unclear to them, we shouldn't be allowed to close questions in other languages just because they are unclear for us. If we want to close something, there should be a rule against it, so I think that something about this should be put in the help section, otherwise there is no real justification for closing the questions. And how are users to know that it's an English only site if it is not officially written anywhere?